# Electret condense microphone(ECM), its external circuit design

Tags: filter, cpu, microphone

I got the external circuit about the Electret condense microphone(ECM), shown as in the below. I would like to know that 1). How it can work out on differential signal to input to CPU? 2). It seems like using so many RC filter, what is its function purpose? 3). What's the filter of blue frame? Thanks.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f6Erru.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Comment: Your title asks about the circuitry **inside** the microphone, but your text asks about something *completely different*. Please fix that.

Comment: This circuit looks unconventional to me. The signal from a microphone is usually too weak to filter and feed to an ADC (in a microcontroller) directly. I expect to see an opamp based circuit with some amplification.

Comment: You can find a load of circuits on Bing images.  They tend to be rather similar.